# Tape Equilibrium Codility Training: Why Does It Return 0?

Tags: c

***I'm not looking for solution posts

I was taking the Tape Equilibrium Codility Training in C and this was how far I got:

```
// you can write to stdout for debugging purposes, e.g.
// printf("this is a debug message\n");
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

int solution(int A[], int N) {
    int difference;
    int smallest;
    int left;
    int right;

    if (N == 1) return 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        right += A[i];
    }

    for (int P = 1; P < N; P++) {
        int val = A[P - 1];
        right -= val;
        left += val;
        difference = abs(left - right);
        if (P == 1) smallest = difference;
        if (difference <= smallest) smallest = difference;
    }
    return smallest;
}
```

I kept getting that my solution was returning 0 (I assume due to the "if (N == 1)" line... I'm not sure why the program is entering that 'if' case considering that the given example is N=5). I gave up and turned this in, and my code returned 0 for all Codility test cases. 
Whenever I commented out that line, the program would return some huge number, I'm not sure why either.

Is there some sort of C principle I'm missing?? I'm going crazy because I have no idea why the program would enter that if case if N!=0.

Comment: `int smallest;` - uninitialised variable and not always set -> *undefined behaviour*

Comment: Ditto with `left+=` and `right+=`, the whole function has indeterminate results. Local variables **must be initialised** before reading them.

Comment: I see now that you contrived to set `smallest` in the first iteration of the `for(P...` loop but the same cannot be said from my other comment, and indeed `smallest` was set with a value derived from the other UB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change initialization code to

```
int smallest = 0;
int left = 0;
int right = 0;
```

And everything should be ok. The reason is that you've got undefined behavior. Also the reason is not in the

```
if (N == 1) return 0;
```

You can add something like

```
printf("%d - %d\n", P, smallest);
```

to the end of the `for` loop and see the result at every step. Also you would see the warnings from the compiler

> Compiler output:
>   func.c: In function 'solution':
>   func.c:19:14: warning: 'left' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
>
> ```
>      left += val;
>           ^
> ```
>
> func.c:13:15: warning: 'right' may be used uninitialized in 
>   this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
>
> ```
>      right += A[i];
>            ^
> ```

Comment: thanks so much, you were right! glad to know I haven't forgotten how to code :D